# How to define map width/height using Matplot Basemap on Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, matplotlib-basemap

### TL; DR

How to I set the map to be exactly 1600x900 px?

### Description

I am trying to draw a map with Jupyter Notebook using [Basemap](https://matplotlib.org/basemap/users/merc.html) library as follows:

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

atlas = Basemap(
    llcrnrlon  =   -10.5, # Longitude lower right corner
    llcrnrlat  =      35, # Latitude lower right corner
    urcrnrlon  =    14.0, # Longitude upper right corner
    urcrnrlat  =    44.0, # Latitude upper right corner
    resolution =     'i', # Crude resolution
    projection = 'tmerc', # Transverse Mercator projection
    lat_0      =    39.5, # Central latitude
    lon_0      =   -3.25  # Central longitude
)

atlas.drawmapboundary(fill_color='aqua')
atlas.fillcontinents(color='#cc9955',lake_color='aqua')
atlas.drawcoastlines()
plt.show()
```

and getting the following result

[image]

Is it possible to make the drawn map larger, defining the minimum width and height it should have?

Comment: Would adjusting the figure size do what you want?(Making sure I understand the question properly)

Comment: I would like to produce a map that is `1600x900 px` passing the dimensions to the constructor, for example, or calling a `Basemap` method.

Comment: Can you be more specific? Do you want to create an image of size 1600x900 pixels? Do you want the map to be 1600x900 pixels? Do you want this to be the saved image or the one shown in the notebook? (In the latter case mind that usually the notebook is less than 1600 pixels wide, are you hence asking for a solution to make the notebook wider?) Note that you can always make the figure much larger, e.g.  `plt.figure(figsize=(20, 15))` and the image will be scaled down to whatever fits into the notebook.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I want the map to be 1600x900 px

Comment: I don't think that is clear enough, given the other questions in my previous comment. But since you already accepted an answer, which does not show how to create a map of given size, the requirement does not seem to be that strict.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I've just started using Matplotlib, but it seems like I'm still thinking like a mobile developer. I thought that the dimensions would be a property of the `Basemap` instance, not defined in the `plt` object (like you and @andrewnagyeb shown).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [*figure*](https://matplotlib.org/api/figure_api.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure).

For example:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(1, 1))
```

Creates an inch-by-inch image, which will be 80-by-80 pixels unless you also give a different dpi argument. 
You can change *dpi* with two possible ways

**Way 1**: Passing it as an argument to the figure as the following:(i.e *300*)

```
plt.figure(figsize=(1, 1),dpi=300)
```

**Way 2**:Passing it to `savefig()`

```
plt.savefig("foo.png", dpi=300)
```

Perfect [Example](http://introtopython.org/visualization_earthquakes.html)

Comment: How do I change the map `dpi`?

Comment: I have added possible ways to the answer. Hopefully, that helps.